# Change the previous output in a terminal when a resize occurs

Tags: bash, terminal

**How can I execute a previous command in the terminal when a resize of terminal occurs**

For example, when I execute the command `ls` in terminal what I get is
when I do a resize what I get is
[Output of `ls` in a short window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOjnz.png)

but when I resize the window to large the previous output of the command does not change and what it looks like is [The preview of previous output when I resize window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3BIo.png)

but I want the terminal to be refreshed itself on resize of the window.

[My desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N7vB.png)

In short, I want a bash script to execute every previous command before or a selected command as a web-browser does.

I had seen the question  already before when I asked this question but that question won't provide me a solution because I want my previous command to be executed but not any functions or any other after commands

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST]
[1]: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

Comment: Along with a text output, I also want to show the size of terminal window, that's why I  uploaded an image

Comment: I guess [checkwinsize](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61584/how-to-solve-the-issue-that-a-terminal-screen-is-messed-up-usually-after-a-res) will help a little, but it won't reflow your pre-formatted `ls` output, the newlines are already there...

Comment: If you have images, don't put links but images

Comment: but I want to reflow my pre-formatted `ls` output